# SSRS - Post Publishing Tasks

Tags: reporting-services, automation

As part of the publishing "best practices" I came up with my own, I tend to archive report groups and republish the "updated" reports.  However, with this stratedgy, I lose users associated with each report or have to rehide reports.

Is there an automated process I can use to hide reports or add users, after deploying form Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Paul Stovell](http://www.paulstovell.com/blog/) posted some examples of [Reporting Services automation](http://svn.paulstovell.net/Projects/ReportingServicesAutomation/trunk/src/) that might get you going.

EDIT: The link to the Subversion repository has been updated and is now working